# Converting bytestream to file in client side using gwt

Tags: java, gwt, byte

I want to convert bytestream in client side using gwt... I tried FileOutputStream but cannot use in client side of gwt.

The scenario is i have a list of bytestream and i want to convert that into file in the client side.

I get the list of bytestream from the server using rpc.

Is there alternative in converting this bytestreamto file without using servelets?

here's my code at the client side

```
private void convertImageToFolder(String designPath,
            ArrayList<FileObject> listFileObj) throws IOException {
        for(FileObject eachFileObj:listFileObj) {
            System.out.println("putting files into " + designPath);
            FileObject fo1 = eachFileObj;
            System.out.println("filename is " + fo1.getFileName());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(designPath + File.separator +new File(fo1.getFileName()));
            fos.write(fo1.getFileBlob());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no files on the client side (and no folders). Browsers do not have access to the local file system - that would be a huge security hole.

If you want a user to save a file, you need to return a file from your servlet.